# Kentor Identify Identity Provider After Acs ReturnUrl

Tags: kentor-authservices

I Have multiple identity providers defined to work with my AuthServices, 
Each of them send a SamlResponse to my AssertionService as is supposed to then  redirect to my RedirectUrl like "ExternalLoginCallback" that is defined in Sustainsys.Saml2.StubIdp example.
I have no way to know witch of Identity provider returned the externalIdentity,
I have to check that the current user belongs this idp.

I hope I don't have to force them to send a special claim with there Idp Id or something like that.

Does it exist a way to pass the entityId between Acs to my callback action ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer...

I extract idp id from  Claim Issuer  like this :

```
 var externalIdentity = context.Authentication.GetExternalIdentity(ExternalCookie.Name);
 var  idp = externalIdentity.FindFirst(AuthServicesClaimTypes.LogoutNameIdentifier)?.Issuer;
```